# Converting Mongoose schema to Prisma Mysql schema

Tags: mysql, mongodb, javascript

I am trying to convert the following Mongoose schema to a Prisma MySql Schema. Not sure if I am doing it right. Here is the Mongoose Schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    products: [
      {
        product: {
          type: ObjectId,
          ref: 'Product',
        },
        count: Number,
        color: String,
        price: Number,
      },
    ],
    cartTotal: Number,
    totalAfterDiscount: Number,
    orderedBy: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export mongoose.models.Cart || mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema);


const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: 'Name is required',
      minlength: [2, 'Too short'],
      maxlength: [32, 'Too long'],
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      index: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export mongoose.models.Category ||
  mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);


const CouponSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
      uppercase: true,
      required: 'Name is required',
      minlength: [6, 'Too short'],
      maxlength: [12, 'Too long'],
    },
    expiry: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    discount: {
      type: Number,
      requred: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export mongoose.models.Coupon || mongoose.model('Coupon', CouponSchema);


const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    products: [
      {
        product: {
          type: ObjectId,
          ref: 'Product',
        },
        count: Number,
        color: String,
      },
    ],
    paymentIntent: {},
    orderStatus: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Not Processed',
      enum: [
        'Not Processed',
        'Cash On Delivery',
        'processing',
        'Dispatched',
        'Cancelled',
        'Completed',
      ],
    },
    orderedBy: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export mongoose.models.Order || mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);



const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      text: true,
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      index: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 2000,
      text: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 32,
    },
    category: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'Category',
    },
    subcategories: [
      {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'SubCategory',
      },
    ],
    quantity: Number,
    sold: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    images: {
      type: Array,
    },
    shipping: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Yes', 'No'],
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Black', 'Brown', 'Silver', 'White', 'Blue'],
    },
    brand: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Microsoft', 'Lenovo', 'ASUS'],
    },
    ratings: [
      {
        star: Number,
        postedBy: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    // toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    // toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

export mongoose.models.Product ||
  mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);


const SubCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: 'Name is required',
      minlength: [2, 'Too short'],
      maxlength: [32, 'Too long'],
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      index: true,
    },
    parent: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Category', required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export mongoose.models.SubCategory ||
  mongoose.model('SubCategory', SubCategorySchema);


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: 'subscriber',
    },
    cart: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    address: String,
    wishlist: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Here is what I have got as a result

```
    datasource db {
      provider = "mysql"
      url      = "mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/database_name"
    }
    
    generator client {
      provider = "prisma-client-js"
    }
    
    model User {
    id            String    @id @default(cuid())
    name          String?
    email         String    @unique
    emailVerified DateTime?
    cart          Cart?
    address       String?
    wishlist      Product[]
    image         String?
    role          Role      @default(USER)
    ratings       Rating[]
    createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
    updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt()
}

model Cart {
    id                 String    @id @default(cuid())
    products           Product[]
    cartTotal          Float?
    totalAfterDiscount Float?
    orderedBy          User?     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId             String    @unique
    createdAt          DateTime  @default(now())
    updatedAt          DateTime  @updatedAt
}

model Category {
    id          String        @id @default(cuid())
    name        String
    slug        String        @unique
    products    Product[]
    subcategories SubCategory[]
    createdAt   DateTime      @default(now())
    updatedAt   DateTime?     @updatedAt
}

model Product {
    id            String        @id @default(cuid())
    title         String
    slug          String        @unique
    description   String
    price         Float
    quantity      Int
    sold          Int           @default(0)
    shipping      Shipping
    color         Color
    brand         Brand
    category      Category      @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
    categoryId    String
    subcategories SubCategory[]
    carts         Cart[]
    users         User[]
    images        Image[]
    ratings       Rating[]
    createdAt     DateTime      @default(now())
    updatedAt     DateTime?     @updatedAt

    @@index([categoryId])
}

model SubCategory {
    id         String    @id @default(cuid())
    name       String
    slug       String    @unique
    category   Category  @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
    categoryId String
    products   Product[]
    createdAt  DateTime  @default(now())
    updatedAt  DateTime  @updatedAt

    @@index([categoryId])
}

enum Role {
    USER
    ADMIN
}

model Image {
    id        String   @id @default(uuid())
    image     String
    product   Product  @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
    productId String
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

    @@index([productId])
}

model Rating {
    id        String   @id @default(cuid())
    star      Int
    postedBy  User?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId    String?
    product   Product? @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
    productId String?
    created   DateTime @default(now())
    updated   DateTime @updatedAt

    @@index([userId])
    @@index([productId])
}

enum Shipping {
    Yes
    No
}

enum Color {
    Black
    Brown
    Silver
    White
    Blue
}

enum Brand {
    Apple
    Samsung
    Microsoft
    Lenovo
    ASUS
}
```

Based on the given Mongoose schemas, the relationships between tables can be inferred as follows:

User and Cart have a one-to-one relationship, where each Cart is associated with a single User. This is indicated by the orderedBy field in the CartSchema, which references the User model.

Category and Product have a one-to-many relationship, where each Category can have multiple Products. This is indicated by the category field in the ProductSchema, which references the Category model.

SubCategory and Product have a many-to-many relationship, where each Product can belong to multiple SubCategorys and each SubCategory can have multiple Products. This is indicated by the subcategories field in the ProductSchema, which is an array of references to the SubCategory model.

User and Product have a many-to-many relationship, where each User can have multiple Products in their wishlist and each Product can be in multiple users' wishlists. This is indicated by the wishlist field in the UserSchema, which is an array of references to the Product model.

Product and Cart have a many-to-many relationship, where each Product can be in multiple Carts and each Cart can have multiple Products. This is indicated by the products field in the CartSchema, which is an array of objects that include a reference to the Product model.

Let me know if it makes sense.